# Use different events for same selector in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, listener

On a grid I need to listen on itemclick and itemkeydown actions, but when I add both of them in my controller then none of them are fired. What is the problem in this code?

How can I listen to keypress event on grid's combobox editor?

http://jsfiddle.net/WRXcw/3/

```
        'definitiontypeform dtpropertylist': {
            itemclick: this.doSelectPropertyGrid
        },
        'definitiontypeform dtpropertylist': {
            itemkeydown: this.doAddInitial
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
'definitiontypeform dtpropertylist': {
    itemclick: this.doSelectPropertyGrid,
    itemkeydown: this.doAddInitial
},
```

You can add multiple events you want to listen to in the same selector.

In your code, you add the same key twice to the control object `'definitiontypeform dtpropertylist'` which results in unwanted behavior.

---

For your Problem in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WRXcw/3/)

> I can't listen to the keypress here. I have a jsfiddle example for that. how can I listen to keyboard on combobox editor in a grid?

Add a listener to the editor config for the events you are interested in e.g.

```
listeners: {
    keydown: function(){
        // your code ...
    }
}
```

And do not forget to enable the [Keyevents](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-enableKeyEvents)  for the combobox.

```
enableKeyEvents: true
```

The full code should be

```
editor: {
        ...
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        listeners: {
            keydown: function(){
                // your code ...
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: thank you andy that was correct but now I have another problem, I can't listen to the keypress here. I have a jsfiddle example for that. how can I listen to keyboard on combobox editor in a grid?